# Scala - Remove type annotation in pattern definition

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types, annotations, matching

```
class MyClass

val list: List[Any] = ...

list match {
  case List(t: MyClass) => 
  case _ => 
}
```

What's wrong with the first case? In IDEA I keep seeing a yellow indicator, telling me to "Remove type annotation from pattern definition".

Comment: What do you want to do? Find `List` or `List[MyClass]`?

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Pls see my comment to Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, assuming you really want to match lists of exactly one element of class `MyClass`. This warning would be useful if you had a `List[MyClass]` in which case the check would be redundant and easily forgotten if the type of list elements changed; possibly the IDEA inspection was intended for these cases, but can't distinguish them from the one you have.

Comment: Make sense. I'm intended to match a list with exactly one element of that type, as you see. Still it's annoying not seeing it turns green. :)

Comment: You may be able to use https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/suppressing-inspections.html. IDEA Scala plugin is actually known for sometimes highlighting correct code as a compilation error; that's quite a bit worse :)